# Internet Explorer error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, internet-explorer-7

I am programming in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (ASP.NET, c#).
When I am debugging, after a couple of clicks or actions, Internet Explorer raises an error: "Internet Explorer has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience."

I use IE7, I uninstalled it, but it also raises an error on IE6.
When I use Mozilla Firefox, it works perfectly.

Anyone suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not being smart but is there problem using only FF for debugging?  It's what I use.

Obviously I have tests run in IE as well.

Comment: @ben_248 of course, but does it need to debug with it.  however, you're on the right track, it would be bad to ignore an issue such as this.  have you tried ie8 out of interest? is this XP, vista or win7?

Comment: Each version of IE raises the error. This is Windows XP Proffesional SP3.

Comment: @ben_248 have you installed sp1 for vs2008?  Is this a complex project?  Can you try debugging even a new one page web application to ensure it isn't the project itself or dependencies?  Was it working before and if so what new software have you installed?

Comment: It was working before, but when I made a new web page application, i get no IE error. Since I have this problem, I experiented with Roles in .NET and created a new default database "aspnetdb.mdf".

Comment: @ben i would guess that the trouble lies with this project and that db in particular and not IE.  I would reword your question and this detail as it will help

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting the eventviewer, you may find useful event logs there.
You can open eventviewer by: 
    `Start->Run type eventvwr and look for items that are marked X icon and see its detail.`

Comment: Eventviewer result:
Faulting application iexplore.exe, version 7.0.6000.16762, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 5.1.2600.5512

Comment: You might try this one:

download and run this:
http://www.spychecker.com/program/hijackthis.html

then copy the log file to:
http://www.hijackthis.de/index.php?langselect=english

This helped me a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is any ajax/javascript error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Is your antivirus and anti-spyware software up to date?  This type of error is also common to virus/trojans.  Try scanning and cleaning to see if this helps.